# Opening Data settings of a specific app in Settings -> Data Usage

Tags: android, android-intent, android-settings

I'm creating an app which requires **Google Play services**. But if the user has *restricted* data usage for **Google Play services**, the task fails if he's connected through mobile data. So as a solution I've prompted user to lift the restriction.

I've managed to go up to the list of data settings using this code:

```
dataUsageIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
            "com.android.settings",
            "com.android.settings.Settings$DataUsageSummaryActivity"));
```

But it seems more convenient if I can get user a one step further. That is inside "Google Play services" setting where we can un-tick the restriction check box. (One less click for the user!)

Is there a way I can call an individual application data setting? As an example...

```
dataUsageIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
            "com.android.settings",
            "com.android.settings.Settings$DataUsageSummaryActivity$GooglePlayservices"));
```

But this doesn't work unfortunately...